# Sorting Pandas Dataframe Based on Date/Time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe created using an Access table. The Date column is formatted as an object and has the following syntax:

2019-12-31 12:55:00

I want to sort the dataframe on ascending date order so converted the column to datetime using:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I then try to sort using the following but it doesn't work. The df looks exactly as it did before:

```
df.sort_values(by='Date')
```

An extract of the df is below. What am I doing wrong?

| Date | RefTT |
| --- | --- |
| 31/12/2019 12:55 | 10107355 |
| 31/12/2020 15:25 | 36643074 |
| 31/12/2020 14:15 | 36868924 |
| 08/01/2019 17:35 | 24763287 |
| 08/01/2019 19:45 | 10073929 |
| 08/01/2019 14:50 | 24132711 |
| 08/01/2019 18:40 | 24576111 |
| 08/01/2019 14:40 | 12255761 |
| 08/01/2019 13:30 | 18443380 |
| 31/12/2020 14:00 | 25106015 |
| 31/01/2019 15:10 | 19629874 |
| 31/01/2019 19:30 | 14505238 |
| 31/01/2020 15:40 | 11930839 |
| 31/01/2020 13:40 | 8753735 |
| 31/01/2020 14:45 | 23523591 |
| 31/01/2020 17:15 | 27388541 |
| 31/01/2021 15:10 | 28575475 |
| 28/02/2019 16:30 | 21470086 |
| 28/02/2019 16:55 | 18136828 |
| 28/02/2019 13:35 | 11896776 |
| 28/02/2019 13:50 | 14708670 |
| 28/02/2019 14:25 | 16095243 |
| 29/02/2020 15:00 | 26641007 |
| 29/02/2020 15:45 | 24342002 |
| 29/02/2020 13:37 | 1532111 |
| 29/02/2020 16:10 | 26684160 |
| 28/02/2021 16:40 | 6320524 |
| 28/02/2021 16:20 | 27632002 |
| 28/02/2021 15:10 | 21104540 |
| 31/03/2019 17:40 | 6896639 |
| 31/03/2021 15:10 | 38036656 |
| 31/03/2021 17:20 | 21281524 |
| 31/03/2021 15:00 | 24986895 |
| 31/03/2021 15:50 | 26600969 |

Comment: `df = df.sort_values(by='Date')` ? Do you assig back?

Comment: pd.to_datetime is tricky. 5/6 times I mess up the actual data.  Try to put the format in: format='%Y%m%d'

Comment: `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)` working? Because if use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` ouput should be different - `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`